# Issue on creating new template project in cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have created a template project in cocos2dx 3.0.  I finished the following command.

```
 ./create_project.py -n  proj1 -k proj2 -l  cpp -p mycompany
```

Proj1 is created successfully.  But i got issue in utility file.

"No member named 'value' in 'std::_1::is_nothrow_copy_constructible

in the line 240 in utility.

```
 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
  pair(const pair& __p)
     _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_copy_constructible<first_type>::value && is_nothrow_copy_constructible<second_type>::value)
    : first(__p.first),
      second(__p.second)
```

Can any one help me to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your compiler version correspond to requirements of cocos2d-x?

Comment: I have checked :  default compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 4.1)

Comment: Looks like it's pretty old, try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command for new project in cmd in this directory:

cocos new MyGame -p com.MyCompany.MyGame -l cpp -d DirectoryPath

After running this command, goto eclipse and select import of "Exisiting Android Code in Workspace", then select only "libcocos2dx" and "proj.android".

I hope it will work. Worked for me.
I hope it helps.